# interchange two image buttons in android interchanging their id instead of changing their resource image

Tags: android

In my program I want to interchange the position of two ImageButtons after clicking any of them .I know that it can be done by interchanging their resource images,But I want to do this by interchangig their id/"button name".Can it be done ? If it cannot be done then what is the solution ?

Comment: `by interchangig their id/"button name"` You should not change the id of a View at run time. The ids are intended to allow you to reference Views that are created statically from an XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the id of a View by using button.setId(int), but that will not interchange the buttons, just it's ids.

What you want could be done if your buttons are on a RelativeLayout. Then, you can retrive the views with findViewById(id) and passing new parameters to them after this. Now imagine button1 is in the left and button2 is at right of button1.

```
//first create the layouts that will change
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.button1);

//notice how it's going to be left of button1, now we must apply params to button2
button2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This should do the work for you. Of course this is a basic example when there's just two buttons in your application. Messing with RelativeLayouts programmatically is dangerous because one single change could mess a lot with your layout. Just change background or create another 2 buttons and swap the ones you already have.

Comment: This seems like a lot more trouble than simply setting the drawable of an `ImageButton`.

Comment: For sure, yeah. I don't see a case where you couldn't swap the drawables, it's the logical way to do it.